# How do you delete a file (located in the same directory that your script is running in) in Python?

Tags: python, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a certain file within the directory that I'm running my Python program in.

```
def erase_custom_file():
    directory=os.listdir(os.getcwd())      
    for somefile in directory:
        if somefile=="file.csv":
           os.remove(???)
```

I'm not sure what my next step should be. I know that `os.remove` takes in a path for a parameter but I'm not sure how to direct it to the file I want. Help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use unlink() and path.join()

```
>>> try:
...  os.unlink(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'file.csv'))
... except OSError, e:
...  print e #file does not exist or you don't have permission
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
os.remove( os.path.join( directory, somefile ) )
```

Comment: +1 for os.path.join - one of the things often poorly reinvented

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete a scratch file you made earlier you can try using temporary files. these will automatically be deleted during garbage collection. 
reference: http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html